# Laravel relationship using same files table for different models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I created a `files` table to store metadata of files and the local path where to find this file.

I want to use this table, for multiple models.

For example, `users` can store a profile picture in this table. But `companies` could have their logo stored in this table. So actually, all models I have that can store a file, are having a relationship to this table.

So in `users` and `companies` I have created a column `file_id`, that refers to the `id` on the `files` table. Because the `files` table can store files for multiple models, I am not storing a `user_id` or `company_id` in the `files table.

Now the question is, how can I add this relationship to the `users` and `companies` table? Because as far as I can see, it requires the `files` table to have the id of `users` or `companies`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a [Polymorphic Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). from the documentation:

> ### Polymorphic Relations
>
> #### Table Structure
>
> Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model on a single association. For example,
>   imagine users of your application can "comment" on both posts and
>   videos. Using polymorphic relationships, you can use a single `comments`
>   table for both of these scenarios. First, let's examine the table
>   structure required to build this relationship:
>
> ```php
> posts
>     id - integer
>     title - string
>     body - text
>
> videos
>     id - integer
>     title - string
>     url - string
>
> comments
>     id - integer
>     body - text
>     commentable_id - integer
>     commentable_type - string
> ```
>
> Two important columns to note are the `commentable_id` and
>   `commentable_type` columns on the `comments` table. The `commentable_id`
>   column will contain the ID value of the post or video, while the
>   `commentable_type` column will contain the class name of the owning
>   model. The `commentable_type` column is how the ORM determines which
>   "type" of owning model to return when accessing the `commentable`
>   relation.
>
> #### Model Structure
>
> Next, let's examine the model definitions needed to build this relationship:
>
> ```php
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>
> class Comment extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * Get all of the owning commentable models.
>      */
>     public function commentable()
>     {
>         return $this->morphTo();
>     }
> }
>
> class Post extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * Get all of the post's comments.
>      */
>     public function comments()
>     {
>         return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
>     }
> }
>
> class Video extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * Get all of the video's comments.
>      */
>     public function comments()
>     {
>         return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
>     }
> }
> ```

So, in your case, your files table structure could look like this:

```php
files
    id - integer
    url - string
    fileable_id - integer // <--- the id of the object
    fileable_type - string // <-- the type of the object (user, company, etc)
```

Then in your models:

**File.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning fileable models.
     */
    public function fileable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```php
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the user's files.
     */
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'fileable');
        // or
        // return $this->morphOne(File::class, 'fileable'); equivalent to hasOne
    }
}
```

**Company.php**

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the company's files.
     */
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'fileable');
        // or
        // return $this->morphOne(File::class, 'fileable'); equivalent to hasOne
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I will check and implement soon. I must say I saw this Polymophic relation, but was thinking it would be easier to add files() to the model and just let Laravel know it needs to search App/File for the same id as users.file_id. Do you have a clarification why this is not possible / not the right way to go? Thanks!

Comment: To start, the `File` model should be a child of the other ones (`User`/`Company`) so this model should store the key of the parent and not the other way around (not saying that this wouldn't work the other way around but just for DB design sake). so that's why `files` should have the `{relation}_id` but given that this `{relation}` is dinamic (`User`/`Company`) hence the introduccion of an additional column: `{relation}_type`.

Answer (score 1):

You are going in right direction.

You can have `users` and `companies` foreign key in your `files` table.

Look in Laravel 5 Polymorphic relations.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

you can have foreign key `fileable_id` and the type of the foreign key `fileable_type`

if you would add a file for `companies` record

Let, say your company id is 24 and Model you are using is `App\Models\Company`

Add following to your File Model `App\File`

```
public function fileableable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And following to your `App\User` and `App\Company`

```
 public function files()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'fileable'); // use morphOne if you want One to One relation
}
```

To create the file for **Company**.

```
$company = Company::find(24);
$company->files()->create([
   'path' => '/folder/myfile.txt',
   'size' => '14585',
   'extension' => 'txt',
]);
```

At this stage you might get `MassAssignmentException`

inside your `App\File` Model

add `$fillable = ['path', 'size' , 'extension'];`

Your record will look like :

```
id   path                size   extension     fileable_id    fileable_type

1  /folder/myfile.txt   14585   txt           24              App\Models\Company
```

Laravel automagically stores the `fileable_id` and `fileable_type` judging by the object calling the relationship method. You dont have to put those manually

**Tip : Always go through the official Docs**